# d3.js radial treed downloads differently to svg

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I was creating a radial tree and trying to download it to SVG but it has some issues

It downloads with those black thick strokes which are not displayed on the webpage.

Any idea where the black lines are coming from?

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
width = +svg.attr("width"),
height = +svg.attr("height"),
g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2 - 15) + "," 
+ (height / 2 + 25) + ")");

var stratify = d3.stratify()
.parentId(function(d) { 
console.log(d.id.substring(0, d.id.lastIndexOf(".")));
return d.id.substring(0, d.id.lastIndexOf(".")); });

var tree = d3.cluster()
tree.size([360, 360])
tree.separation(function(a, b) { return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 2) / 
a.depth; });


d3.csv("flare.csv", function(error, data) {
 if (error) throw error;

 var root = tree(stratify(data)
  .sort(function(a, b) { return (a.height - b.height + 100) || 
a.id.localeCompare(b.id); }));

 var link = g.selectAll(".link")
.data(root.descendants().slice(1))
.enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return "M" + project(d.x, d.y)
        + "C" + project(d.x, (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2)
        + " " + project(d.parent.x, (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2)
        + " " + project(d.parent.x, d.parent.y);
  });

link.attr('stroke', function(d) {
   if (d.id.startsWith("Mother.Biological")){
      return "#386eff";
    }
    if (d.id.startsWith("Mother.Env")){
      return "#45cbf2";
    }
    else return '#70f2ad';
    });
var node = g.selectAll(".node")
.data(root.descendants())
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", function(d) { return "node" + (d.children ? " node--
internal" : " node--leaf"); })
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + project(d.x, 
d.y) 
+ ")"; });

node.append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) { 
  console.log(d.value);
  if (d.id == "Mother") return 4.4;
  else return 2.4;
  } )
  .style('fill', function(d) { 
   if (d.id.startsWith("Mother.Biological")){
      return "#386eff";
    }
     if (d.id.startsWith("Mother.Env")){
      return "#45cbf2";
    }
   if (d.id.startsWith("Mother.Biological")){
      return "#386eff";
    }
     if (d.id.startsWith("Mother.Form")){
      return '#70f2ad';
    }
  d.color = 'red';

  return d.color});

  node.append("text")
  .attr("dy", ".31em")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x < 180 === !d.children ? 6 : -6; })
  .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 === !d.children ? 
"start" : "end"; })
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x < 180 ? d.x - 90 
: d.x + 90) + ")"; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.id.substring(d.id.lastIndexOf(".") + 1); });
});

function project(x, y) {
  var angle = (x - 90) / 180 * Math.PI, radius = y;
  return [radius * Math.cos(angle), radius * Math.sin(angle)];
}

d3.select("#download")
.on("mouseover", writeDownloadLink);

function writeDownloadLink(){
var html = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("title", "svg_title")
    .attr("version", 1.1)
    .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
    .node().parentNode.innerHTML;

d3.select(this)
    .attr("href-lang", "image/svg+xml")
    .attr("href", "data:image/svg+xml;base64,\n" + btoa(html))
    .on("mousedown", function(){
        if(event.button != 2){
            d3.select(this)
                .attr("href", null)
                .html("Use right click");
        }
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(){
        d3.select(this)
            .html("Download");
    });
```

};

It looks ok in any browser but when I download it and convert it to SVG or EFM it comes back with those lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page that you provided contains **style tag**. I'm not sure how exactly do you export SVG, but **some css rules seems to be lost** along the way.

In similar case I managed to get current css properties and put them into style property:

```
d3.selectAll('...').each(function() {
  var that = d3.select(this);
  ['stroke', 'stroke-width', 'opacity', 'fill', ...].forEach(function(property) {
    that.style(property, that.style(property))
  });
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the reply and you are right, the CSS property is being dropped somewhere in the conversion.  I was able to get it to work in SVG, but converting from SVG to EMF now is having the same issue. One way I can fix it is to add inlines on the link by wrting style="fill: none" on each link tag but its cumbersome. Is there a way to force in line style in D3?

Comment: Do you mean ```d3.selectAll('a').style('fill', 'none')```?